# Download folder through ftp server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, ftp

I'm trying to write code to download a folder from a FTP server. I looked at the support on gems for ftp downloading. So far, I see syncftp gem is updated most often. Do we have any other options for FTP gem similar to syncftp?

If not, can anyone show me how to download a whole folder from a ftp server connection. I'm able to establish FTP connection and get the list of files from it, but I don't know how to download the entire folder.

Comment: Once you get a list of files and sub-folder, you can download them one by one. That's how FTP programs download "an entire folder", they just traverse them down. Are you looking for a gem that can do this for you?

Comment: yes, can you recommend me if there is a gem that does downloading?

Comment: Although SO is not a place to ask for recommendations, you can try [Vritual File System](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/vfs/basics.html).

Comment: For some reason, the useful responses in Google were few and far between for this question.  This seems to be a popular choice: http://net-ssh.github.io/sftp/v2/api/index.html